# AWS S3 is not working with Django showing AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
#STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.storages.MediaStore'

#MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Showing this error while executing `python manage.py collectstatic`

```
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 348, in copy_file
    self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 437, in _save
    params = self._get_write_parameters(name, content)
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 495, in _get_write_parameters
    params.update(self.get_object_parameters(name))
  File "/home/manish/workspace/gariya/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 511, in get_object_parameters
    return self.object_parameters.copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

storages.py

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStore(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

even I appended static_root and media_root in `urls.py` ( url_patterns[]).
please suggest what's wrong with the settings.py file or something.
when I do collectstatic on my local its working fine. but its not working with AWS S3 integration.

Comment: What is the value for `AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS` in your settings?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}`